# How to enable "Adsense for mobile devices"?

Tags: adsense

On my site, I've got a standard 336px ad unit. I just viewed the site on blackberry and noticed that the ads dont show there.

What's the skinny on how to enable adsense ads on mobile devices? Would I have to recode my WordPress theme to display mobile ads instead of the large rectangle or can this be automatically handled by the adsense script somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is for sure not in the wordpress theme. If you see the ad in normal browser you should see it in your phone's browser too.

Do you see adsense ads on other sites using your phone?